# How does this N-type MOSFET AND-gate work?

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, parallel

[image]

The OUTPUT 'F' is completely seperated from the transistors 'a' and 'b.' The MOSFET infront of 'F' seems to be perpetually on. What makes this a logic gate. Shouldn't F always be on?

Comment: Consider what you would do to turn mosfet F off...

Comment: Looks like you and this guy https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/51837/and-gate-design-using-mosfets have borrowed the same image (without attribution).

Answer (score 3):

If A and B are on, the gate of mosfet F is drawn low.

If one of A or B is off, the gate of mosfet F is pulled up.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't F always be on

If the transistors are properly sized then no. As you can see 'F' is the output of the inverter which has a NMOS in pull down path and resistor in pull up path. If the NMOS is off then surely F is high. But if NMOS is on, then the output voltage at 'F' will be given by the ratio of the on-resistance of NMOS (\$R_{nmos}\$) and the pull up resistor (\$R\$). Mathematically,
$$V_{F} = \frac{R_{nmos}}{R_{nmos} + R}.$$
If \$R_{nmos} \ll R\$, \$V_F\$ will be sufficiently low to be registered as a logical zero. But if these resistances are comparable then you are right this gate would not work.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is incorrect:

> The OUTPUT 'F' is completely seperated from the transistors 'a' and 'b.'

There is an N-channel enhancement FET controlling output F. The gate of the FET is pulled up by a resistor, so that when either FET 'a' or FET 'b' is in cutoff, the gate of FET 'f' is pulled up to the 5V supply rail. Since it is an N-channel enhancement FET (and presumably has a logic-level gate threshold), when Vgs exceeds its threshold voltage, a conductive channel appears between drain and source, pulling output F low.

*The Art of Electronics* chapter 3 goes into FETs in detail, and chapter 9 describes elementary digital circuit design.

Answer (score 0):

The first two FETs (from left) together with the pull-up resistor forms a NAND gate. Because the output will be always high except when \$a=1,\ b=1\$.

The final FET along with the resistor is an NMOS inverter. On cascading they form an AND gate.